# Why react is dispatching action works both sides?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I working on my web app
I set there a store with react redux, 
I have a form with 4 input type number which after pressing a button dispatching to the store as an array, then I have some others inputs that I’d like to get a value of the first 4 as a placeholders but when I change the value it should update the right place in the store , here is my problem , when I change its value (by typing) it change all the values in all the arrays connected in the store 
It’s like the store works both sides , is there way to stop it ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your exact problem is without any code, but it sounds to me like you are overwriting the whole state of your array. Again, I can't be sure without code, but my suggestion is you spread existing state, and add your new array or whatever it is to the end in your reducer where that action is defined.

```
return [...state, action.newData]
```